# Using Pip commands does not work, pip cannot find python

Tags: python

I have Python 3.6.7 installed, launching a program that needs it works, but trying to use any pip command fails as if Python is not installed.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when altering Path in System Environmental variables I had accidentally overwritten everything instead of adding. 
So the path to the python install was lost and pip could not find it.

It was fixed by adding the Python path back into Environmental variables.